# can't find the netbeans 6.x.x jdk bundle

Tags: java, netbeans

the current netbeans bundle page is at the following:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

I really want to get hold of the older version especially 6.7.1 downwards

it normally bundle with the jdk 5 or jdk6

did google it for a while, nothing came up, and one got the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i could not find the bundle that Oracle at some point provided, I was able to find archived versions of both Netbeans and the SDK. You can find the [Netbeans archive](http://services.netbeans.org/downloads/dev.php) here (version [6.7.1 is here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/6.7.1/index.html)). The JDK archive can be found at [this location](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html), with versions 5 and 6 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html), respectively. If you for some reason need some help with installing this, you can use the Netbeans [install instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/install.html) for version 6.7.1.

I would hazard to guess that this is a close as you can get to the original bundle, unless it is still archived out there. There is probably a Wayback Machine archive out there somewhere, but I could not find it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: couldn't find the bundle was exactly the problem I got. nowadays we don't even have jdk 5 or early version of 6 on or machine. to specify the jdk at netbeans installation time, we need to change the config file in the config folder.